# Error: 'split' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Android Studio throws this following NullSafety error on `split` in Flutter.

```
The method 'split' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.  Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!'). Open documentation
```

But none of the suggested fixes work. Heres' the code;

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: jwtOrEmpty,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
        if(snapshot.data != "") {
          var str = snapshot.data;
          var jwt = str.split(".");

          if(jwt.length !=3) {
            return LoginPage();
          } else {
            var payload = json.decode(ascii.decode(base64.decode(base64.normalize(jwt[1]))));
            if(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(payload["exp"]*1000).isAfter(DateTime.now())) {
              return HomePage(str, payload);
            } else {
              return LoginPage();
            }
          }
        } else {
          return LoginPage();
        }
      }
  ),
```

I'm guessing it's because the returned `snapshot.data` can't be null. But I'm not sure what I can do about it. I tried adding "!" and "?" to  `snapshot.data`, `str`, `jwt` and `split`but nothing works.

Comment: `str?.split(".")` or `str?.split?.call(".")` should work
or `str!.split(".")` if you are sure it's not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Android Studio said otherwise, it looks like the problem wasn't with Null safety but because "str" wasn't really a string. So I did this;

```
var str = snapshot.data;
var jwt = str.toString().split(".");
```

Also, I had to add `// @dart=2.9` to the top of the file as the flutter storage dependency does not support NULL SAFETY.

Answer (score 0):

What it is trying to say is that your `str` could be null because `snapshot.data` could be null.

So one way to use it would be,

```
var jwt = str!.split('.'); // This means we are saying that str will never be null.
```

But obviously, this would crash if `str` was actually `null` at runtime.

Better way to do it,

```
var str = snapshot.data;
var jwt = [];

if (str != null)
  jwt = str.split(".");
```

Assuming your `snapshot.data` is a string, this will never crash since we are putting a null check.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither worked. "split" is still showing red.

Comment: @Meggy could you elaborate on what it means that it is still `showing red` ? is it showing a warning ?

Comment: It was the "split" part of  "jwt = str.split" which was underlined red. Though Android Studio claimed it was a null safety error, in fact it's because "str" wasn't actually a string but an object. Doing this solved the problem-  str.toString()

Comment: Oh okay. your issue is resolved now then ?

Comment: Yes. I posted the answer. Thanks!